# How to migrate a MySQL 5.7 database to MySQL 8.0?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, sql

Currently I have a Drupal 8 site in production with a database on MySQL 5.7

How to migrate a MySQL 5.7 database to MySQL 8.0?

Do I just need to export my Drupal 8 database from MySQL 5.7 and import it into a MySQL 8.0 database?

Is there any manipulation to do on the tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to migrate a MySQL 5.7 database to MySQL 8.0?

This will likely depend on your DB and the product using it.

I would start by using my [favourite search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate%20mysql%205.7%20to%20mysql%208) to find information. I would then read through some of the information sources it provided to get a feel for what is involved. In particular the [first link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-migration.html) from my favourite search engine seems like a good place to start, it contains further information sources which appear interesting and pertinent A.8.1 particularly. I would probably do [additional searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=updating%20drupal%20from%20mysql%205.7%20to%20mysql%208) more closely related to the products I was upgrading and do further reading.

Having done my background reading, made notes etc I would write a plan for updating my system. I would test this plan by using a staging environment and refine my plan as required.

When I was happy with mu plan I would implement it through my change process.

> Is there any manipulation to do on the tables ?

This will likely depend upon your tables.

Comment: Sir, your talking down deserves some reprimand. You should realize that people come here only after going to that search engine first. This kind of answer is not acceptable not only from what I said above but also that it does not address the subject matter. I would rather have this question deleted than read such kind of answer

Comment: You are wildly incorrect in believing that people use search engines before coming here to ask questions.

Comment: OK, I will make an exception in your case then. google does a far better search than the likes of SO and besides you assume that the first search result leads you to the answer. Actually no, at the moment it leads one right here with someone mouthing off at them